# How to query an XML File with E4X in AS3?

Tags: sql, xml, flash, actionscript-3, e4x

I need to archive a database-driven flash as3 website.
I exported a table to xml so now i have something like this:

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <id>home</id>
    <msg>bodytext</msg>
    <type>0</type>
    <lastEditDate>0000/0/0 00:00:00</lastEditDate>
    <lastAccessDate>2009/6/17 11:37:21</lastAccessDate>
    <timesAccessed>855</timesAccessed>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <id>contact</id>
    <msg>contact body text</msg>
    <type>0</type>
    <lastEditDate>0000/0/0 00:00:00</lastEditDate>
    <lastAccessDate>2010/5/6 20:40:46</lastAccessDate>
    <timesAccessed>831</timesAccessed>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Now I would like to select the RECORD where **id** is set to **home**.

In SQL: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='home'`

How can i do the same thing with E4X for AS3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it is as easy as this:

```
xml.RECORD.(id == 'home')
```

this will return the following:

```
<RECORD>
    <id>home</id>
    <msg>bodytext</msg>
    <type>0</type>
    <lastEditDate>0000/0/0 00:00:00</lastEditDate>
    <lastAccessDate>2009/6/17 11:37:21</lastAccessDate>
    <timesAccessed>855</timesAccessed>
  </RECORD>
```